# getting error while saving the record in angular with php.

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Currently i am doing project in angular.js application. I am using server as php. in that while saving the record in angular js, I am getting error. I have upload my code below.

HTML CODE:

```
<div  ng-controller="theaterController">
<div class="col-md-12" ng-if="isCreating">
<form class="form-horizontal" name="saveForm" method="post">
    <h4>Create</h4>
    <p class="danger">{{error}}</p>
    <p class="success">{{msgs}}</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="theaterName" class="col-md-offset-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
          <input type="text" name="theatername" class="form-control" id="theaterName" placeholder="Enter theater name" ng-modal="theatername" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-8">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-ng-click="submitForm()" id="submit">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="cancelCreating()" id="Cancel" value="Cancel">
        </div>  
     </div>
</form>
```

Angular.js code:

```
app.controller('theaterController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.message = 'Theater';
$http.get('ajax/theater-master.php',{"getElement": "get_data"}).success(    function (response){
    //console.log(response);
    $scope.theaters = response;
});

//save form code;
$scope.submitForm = function (){
    var url = 'ajax/theater-master-save.php';
    var d1 = {'name': $scope.theatername };
     $http.post(url, d1
    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.msg != '')
        {
            $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.errors.push(data.error);
        }
    }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
// or server returns response with an error status.
        $scope.errors.push(status);
    });
}



}]);
```

theater-master-save.php:

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->name);
echo $usrname ;
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `theater` (theater) VALUES ("' . $usrname . '")");
if($query){
    $arr = array('message' => 'Theater master created successfully', 'error' => '');
    $arrjson = json_encode($arr);
    echo $arrjson;
}else{
    $arr = array('message' => '', 'error' => 'error in inserting record');
    $arrjson = json_encode($arr);
    echo $arrjson;
}

?>
```

ERROR:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
script.js:52 <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$name in    <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\angular-ticketbooking\ajax\theater-master-save.php</b> on    line <b>3</b><br />

angular.min.js:107 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
at script.js:55
at angular.min.js:87
at angular.min.js:119
at n.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
at n.$digest (angular.min.js:130)
at n.$apply (angular.min.js:133)
at h (angular.min.js:87)
at K (angular.min.js:91)
at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (angular.min.js:93)(anonymous function) @     angular.min.js:107(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:80(anonymous function) @    angular.min.js:119n.$eval @ angular.min.js:133n.$digest @   angular.min.js:130n.$apply @ angular.min.js:133h @ angular.min.js:87K @    angular.min.js:91z.onload @ angular.min.js:93
```

I am new to angular js, I am just practising angular.js by trying crud operation in angular. I have just tried this above code, I am getting error like this. Please tell me where i am going worng.
Thanks in advance

Comment: As Keithm said you need to include jQuery in this page.

Comment: thank for you reply friends, My input value not going to server side, I dont know whether i am correct of getting value in server side. $name is getting undefined property

Comment: are you able to hit the service from browser?

Comment: No i am not, when type some value and click submit, i call one function in script file (submitForm). After that i gave http.post to get my value and send to ajax/theater-master-save.php . I want that data to save in my mysql database, For that i am not getting modal.theater value in server, I dont know i am doing correct or worng. If worng please give the correct was to post value to database using angular.js

Comment: @Vijaykarthik - I have updated my answer. You have a typo in your HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like you are getting two errors and you have a typo in your HTML:

**1) "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery"**

This is because Bootstrap requires jQuery and you have not added the jQuery library to your HTML page. You need to include jQuery in your HTML page by adding the following script tag:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>`

**2) "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"**

This is because you are trying to push something into $scope.msgs but Angular does not what $scope.msgs is because you have not defined it. You need to define $scope.msgs in your Controller before you can add something to it like so: `$scope.msgs = [];` You also need to define `$scope.errors` in the same way.

**3) Use ng-model not ng-modal**

In your HTML you have a typo. You have typed `ng-modal` instead of `ng-model` and this is why the value is not getting sent to the server. You need to change your HTML to:
`<input type="text" name="theatername" class="form-control" id="theaterName" placeholder="Enter theater name" ng-model="theatername" required>`

Comment: $scope.msgs is not required to be defined.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am asking for server side issue they are script.js:52 <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$name in    <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\angular-ticketbooking\ajax\theater-master-save.php</b> on    line <b>3</b><br />.....my data going to server side.

Comment: @MukeshKumar Yes it is - he is trying to push something into $scope.msgs which is not defined and is giving the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I missed @Keithm

Comment: @MukeshKumar Did you downvote my answer because of this? If so, would you mind upvoting it again?

Comment: Please edit your answer to make it work. Please elaborate your answer by adding comment like Cannot read property 'push' of undefined'.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more information on the errors reported in the question.

Comment: I got for first two, but in server i cannot able to get model value. Which was i changed that ng-modal to ng-model. I am getting same error <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$name in <b>

Comment: my ng-model="theatername" is undefined in controller $scope.theatername. my value not get fetching